# Shadow Layout with 9-patch and background color transparent?

Tags: android, shadow, nine-patch

I would like to add a custom layout an edge with shadow, exactly one like this:
http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

The problem is that I use this to add a semi / transparent background color: (corners_main_layout.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="6dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark" />
</shape>
```

So I can not use for background 9-patch.

Is there any way to 9-patch with shadows and transparent background color?

If not .... How could make the effect?

PS: I have seen many custom XML to add shadows, but all are very poor.

Here example:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_recover_pass"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="...RecoverPassActivity"
android:background="@mipmap/fondo_01"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/corners_main_layout">

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I Need shadow border rectangle White (it is transparent) similar to example 9-patch

------------EDIT---------------
I modified mi corners_main_layout.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/shadow_custom" />
```

and result :-( :
[image]

Comment: Could you not simply wrap your existing layout inside a [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)?

Comment: Jokes apart... what does it take to make a LayerList with the 9 patch stacked over your "filled rectangle" shape and use that combo as your View background?

Comment: I'm sorry about "september" .... I write from the mobile phone

Comment: see .... What I want is to add a similar shade shadow generator 9-patch several layout I have.

I thought it was a good choice to use 9-ptach to generate the shadows of my layout, the problem is I can not add a transparent background.

CardView can not use it.
I need to add the shadow effect + background transparent to various sections of my app color, but not CardView ...

Comment: Still unclear. Mind to post a picture of what you desire and what you get instead?

Comment: OK. Now make a LayerList with the 9 patch overlayed onto the rounded rect and you're done. Or simply include the fill color inside the 9 patch.

Comment: thanks! i dont know layer-list :-S..... I have almost, but not I finish fix it, look new screenshot

Comment: Looks nice, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

yeah! i have solution!

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/shadow_custom_9patch"/>
</layer-list>
```

thanks for help!

Comment: Well, the 9 patch item should be the **last** one, so that it sits **on top** of the other ones.